# How to run Micronaut App with OAuth2 in Docker

Tags: java, docker, micronaut

I'm trying to run Micronaut App in Docker.
If I run micronaut via gradle on local machine like `gradlew run` everything is fine.
But if I built an image and run it with docker-compose I get error

`Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.OauthClientConfiguration] exists for the given qualifier: @Named('fb'). Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).`

Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN ./gradlew dockerBuild
RUN ./gradlew build -x test
FROM openjdk:14-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/server-*-all.jar server.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", "-Xmx128m", "-jar", "server.jar"]
```

Comment: what happens when you run the jar on your local machine?

Comment: @IEE1394 It works fine

Comment: just to make shure - instead of running docker build you run "java -jar /app/build/libs/server-*-all.jar"

Comment: how do you build the jar? using that https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow ? maybe give jib a try

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-guides/creating-your-first-micronaut-app-kotlin/blob/master/complete/Dockerfile

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-guides/creating-your-first-micronaut-app-kotlin/blob/master/complete/build.gradle

Comment: @IEE1394 yes, I'm just run java -jar server.jar, and it works fine

Comment: sounds like you packaging your container wrong (maybe without dependencies) .. do you use shadow to build the container?

Comment: i meant jib sorry not shadow